# Issue with Angular Router Resolve - Data undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-routing, rxjs5

I have a route in my application that I've attached a resolver to it so that before the route is accessed I have the data needed for the page. These last few days I've been updating the application from Angular 4 to Angular 5 and as part of the update I'm also changing the code to use the `HttpClientModule` rather than the deprecated `HttpModule` and `rxjs` 5.5.6.

For some reason the resolver is now always returning undefined as the data. This is a sample of the resolver I have:

```
@Injectable()
export class GameLoaderResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private service1: Service1,
        private service2: Service2
    ) { }

    resolve(): Observable<any> {
        let observable1 = this.service1.get('http://localhost:1234/api/Users/getData');

        let observable2 = this.service2.get('http://localhost:1234/api/Countries/getData');

        return forkJoin(observable1, observable2);
    }
}
```

Above is a sample of what I have in my resolver. I need data from multiple service calls before the route loads so I'm using `forkJoin` to combine them into one single `Observable`. What happens with the above code is that an array with an element for each observable is returned. So in this case an array with two elements are returned, index `0` has the data of `observable1` and index `1` has the data of `observable2`. After I changed to using `HttpClient` and `rxjs` 5.5.6 I'm getting an array `[ undefined, undefined ]`.

This used to work when using `HttpModule`, I did my research and unless I missed it I couldn't find any changes to the router resolvers, so I'm not sure if there's anything wrong with the code above.

**Environment Verions:**

- **Angular:** 5.2.8
- **RXJS:** 5.5.6

**Update**

I managed to fix the issue by using `map` on each observable and on the `forkJoin`, this way the result is returned. So the updated code has to look something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class GameLoaderResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private service1: Service1,
        private service2: Service2
    ) { }

    resolve(): Observable<any> {
        let observable1 = this.service1.get('http://localhost:1234/api/Users/getData')
            .map(res => return res);

        let observable2 = this.service2.get('http://localhost:1234/api/Countries/getData')
            .map(res => return res);

        return forkJoin(observable1, observable2)
            .map(res => return res);
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that since before when using `HttpModule` we had to implement a  function to extract the data from the response, the data was being returned. Now with the latest update I'm guessing that this has to be done with an "extra step".

Comment: Use Observable.zip(observable1, observable2)

Comment: Actually I just solved it, I'll update my question

Answer (score 0):

The previous `forkJoin` is deprecated. So just modify your `forkJoin` to the following format:

```
return forkJoin([observable1, observable2]);
```

What essentially we are doing is simply creating an array of observables that are to be returned.

I am assuming that your app-routing.module.ts file contains code something like this below:

```
{
    path: 'gameloader',
    resolve: {
      resolvedData: GameLoaderResolver
    },
    loadChildren: () => import('./gameloader/gameloader.module').then(m => m.GameLoaderPageModule)
},
```

In your GameLoader component, you can access the observables in the following way:

```
if (this.route.snapshot.data.resolvedData[0]) { 
    // The following gives the value of observable1
    console.log(resolvedData[0]);
}

if (this.route.snapshot.data.resolvedData[1]) { 
    // The following gives the value of observable2
    console.log(resolvedData[1]);
}
```

Try out the above and let me know how that goes for you. Good luck!